# Ubuntu 20.04 clevis-luks setup auto unlocking not working

Tags: lvm, luks, cryptsetup, tpm

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine setup that I am trying to configure for disk encryption. I am trying to setup auto unlock, but my configuration has not worked so far, and I am always prompted for a password.

To do this I followed the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install cryptsetup`
2. Check /dev/nvme0n1p3 -> `sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p3` -> No Tokens or Keyslots
3. Install `clevis`, `clevis-luks`, `clevis-dracut`, `clevis-udisks2`, `clevis-systemd`, `clevis-tpm2`
4. `sudo clevis luks list -d /dev/nvme0n1p3` -> Empty
5. `echo <my password> | sudo clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{ "pcr_bank":"sha256", "pcr_ids": "7,11" }'`
6. `sudo dracut -fv --regenerate-all`
7. Check `sudo clevis luks list -d /dev/nvme0n1p3` -> `1: tpm2 '{"hash":"sha256","key":"ecc","pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"7,11"}'`
8. `lsblk -o NAME,UUID,MOUNTPOINT` ->

```
├─nvme0n1p1                 <uuid1>                              /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                 <uuid2>   /boot
└─nvme0n1p3                 <uuid3>   
  └─dm_crypt-0              <uuid4> 
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv <uuidd5>   /
```

9. `cat /etc/crypttab` -> `dm_crypt-0 UUID=<uuid3> none luks`

When booting I do not notice any errors for cryptsetup, luks, tpm2. Googling around and checking others questions, I have also verified tried:

1. `sudo systemctl enable clevis-luks-askpass.path`
2. `update-initramfs -c -k all` -> Runs successfully

My fstab file doesn't actually list the encrypted partition:
`cat /etc/fstab` ->

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/<Some id which I don't know the origin of> / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid2> /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid1> /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

I've also tried manually adding in the partition to fstab but did not work.

No matter what I try, it always asks for password on boot.

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing: `clevis-initramfs` that needed to be installed. Once added the auto unlocker worked.